# Android: Question on Payouts for apps

Tags: android

The information on the Marketplace website and Google Checkout isn't completely clear to me. Is google going to make a deposit to my bank account from Google Checkout for every app I sell, or will it all sit in my Google Checkout account until I decide to move it to my bank? It would seem silly to do the first because most banks put a limit on the number of free transactions you get per month. So if you have an app that sells at all well for $1 and google takes $0.30 that leaves you $0.70. Then after your accounts transaction limit your bank make take up to $0.50 per transaction leaving you with just $0.20 per sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, payouts are made for a day's worth of sales at a time on weekdays and lag behind actual sales by 2 days (e.g., sales made on Tuesday hit your account on Thursday). No payouts are made on Saturdays, Sundays, or holidays (e.g., Monday, you'll get paid for Thursday, Friday, and Saturday's sales).

Comment: To qualify that, my app also sells for $10 a pop, though, so if there is a minimum amount that triggers a payout, I would seem to hit it every day. Not sure if that's the case if you're selling a $1 app.

Comment: UPDATE: As of February, 2011, Google has changed the payout structure such that payouts are now made once per month. "For transactions submitted for capture within a calendar month, we will transfer funds to your Settlement Account before close of business on the 15th day of the following calendar month. For example, if your account is linked and a transaction is submitted for capture on February 22, 2011, the payout for that transaction would occur before the close of business on March 15, 2011."

Answer (score 2):

It trickles in, every couple of days you'll get a deposit. My app sells anywhere from 2-5 copies a day, I get 69 cents for every sale and it seems about every other day or so I get a small deposit into my bank account.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember well it's every week or every month transactions from google to your account.

But i'm not sure.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a payout until at least $1 is ready to be paid out (so if you sell a $1 app, it's at the very least every 2 sales).  It pays out as soon as possible after you have at least $1 sitting in your account, on weekdays.  You'll see a couple of days difference in the payouts and when you actually made the sells, but you get your money pretty quickly.